# So, I got a question. Is it possible to have a embed welcome message in a Discord bot that gets deleted after a few seconds?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
var TOKEN = ""
const client = ("TOKEN");
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const channel = ("CHANNELID");


const embed = new MessageEmbed() 
('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setDescription(`Welcome ${member}! You are the ${membercount}th member!`)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
                 
                  
})
```

That is my current code for this but, I'm unsure because there are some errors to it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more details for the question and the expectation. Please also add the research work you did for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Please don't use this code, it will not work based on how you have it coded now

```js
var TOKEN = ""
const client = ("TOKEN");
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const channel = ("CHANNELID");


const embed = new MessageEmbed() 
('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setDescription(`Welcome ${member}! You are the ${membercount}th member!`)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
                 

      
})
```

Please use the code below:

```js
// var TOKEN = "" //token is never a variable
// const client = ("TOKEN"); //please find a different way to code this as this will cause confusion later on

const TOKEN = ""
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [], // pick the intents you need here https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents
})

client.login(TOKEN)

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeChannel = client.channels.cache.get("channel_id")
    const membercount =  member.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size
    const timeout = 30 * 1000 //30 being how many seconds till the message is deleted.

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle(`${member.displayName} has joined us!`)
        .setDescription(`Welcome ${member}!\nYou are member number ${membercount}!`)
        .setThumbnail(member.displayAvatarURL())

    welcomeChannel.send({
        embeds: [embed]
    }).then((message) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            message.delete()
        }, timeout);
    })
})
```